# Top ActionBar covers pages content

Tags: android, xml, android-actionbar

I'm creating an android app and I've just added a Navigation drawer into one of my activities. I've successfully added it in, however, it now overlaps the content of the page. The jobs text and the rest should be below the ActionBar.
I've tried adding a margin to the top of the jobs text which does push it down as I wish. Is there a better way to move it down?

[image: Content Overlap]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/jobListPage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="top"
        tools:context="com.kitkat.crossroads.Jobs.JobsActivity">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView5"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Jobs"
                android:fontFamily="@font/bebasneueregular"
                android:textSize="30dp"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="163dp"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="16dp" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textName"
                    android:layout_width="125dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/bebasneueregular"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:text="Job Name"
                    android:textSize="15dp"
                    android:textColor="#FF000000"
                    android:visibility="visible" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textFrom"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/bebasneueregular"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textName"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:text="From"
                    android:textSize="15dp"
                    android:textColor="#FF000000"
                    android:visibility="visible" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textTo"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/bebasneueregular"
                    android:textSize="15dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:text="To"
                    android:textColor="#FF000000"
                    android:visibility="visible" />


            </LinearLayout>


            <ExpandableListView
                android:id="@+id/jobListView12345"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />


        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_header"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Becoz you assign the `gravity="top"` in Linearlayout so its happens

so u remove this `gravity` see my below code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/jobListPage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        //remove gravity="top" from hear
        tools:context="com.kitkat.crossroads.Jobs.JobsActivity">
```

if your problem not solve then u can take `android:layout_marginTop="20dp"` in **inner Linearlayout**

see below code

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">
```

**Don't take a  *include* in LinearLayout. Becoz its change your  actionbar** so u can only remove `gravity` and assign `margin top`

Comment: Thanks, removing the gravity and adding the margin worked nicely. I tried including the <include> inside the LinearLayout, however, it removed the actionbar on the top for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should put

```
<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

inside

```
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/jobListPage"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="top"
    tools:context="com.kitkat.crossroads.Jobs.JobsActivity">
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why I was having the overlap was because I put the page content in the `activity_main.xml` layout and not the `content_main.xml`. Putting the content in that layout sorted the issue out and put the content below the action bar.